# Npgsql v3.0.0 RC2 Contains Duplicate Definitions

Tags: visual-studio-2013, npgsql

I recently updated my Npgsql version via NuGet from 2.2.3 to 3.0.0-RC2.  When I build, I am now getting a bunch of errors of the form:

```
The type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection' exists in both
    'somePath\packages\Npgsql.3.0.0-rc0002\lib\net45\CodeContracts\Npgsql.Contracts.dll'
and 'somePath\packages\Npgsql.3.0.0-rc0002\lib\net45\Npgsql.dll'
```

The same is true for types `NpgsqlPoint`, `NpgsqlPolygon`, and `NpgsqlException`.  I tried to clean and re-build the solution, and to close and re-open Visual Studio (2013 Ultimate Update 4).  Neither approach had any effect.  Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been fixed in the 3.0 release branch, see github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/668. The nuget for 3.0 won't contain the contract reference assembly.

Comment: For anyone else searching: the solution to fix it until the actual 3.0 release is to manually remove the reference to Npgsql.Contracts.